# Should we avoid using wait/notify/notifyAll explicitly

Tags: java, multithreading

My question is about using `wait()` and `notify()` explicitly. Whould we try to avoid it every time we need something like `producer-consumer` and consider to use `BlockingDeque` instead.

I tried to think about it and didn't find more or less reasonble explanation. Moreover I tried to invent example where we would have to use `wait()` and `notify()` explicitly and failed.

Comment: Wait and notify are _low-level_ primitives that are meant for implementing higher-level synchronization objects (queues, semaphores, barriers, ...)  There's nothing wrong with using wait() and notify(), but always ask yourself, "Am I re-inventing something that somebody's already done?"  The java.util.concurrent package and third party packages like guava and Apache commons provide a lot of high-quality, and very useful classes that you should not try to re-invent for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better higher level constructs in `java.util.concurrent`, so using `wait/notify` nowadays is highly dubious.

Comment: Which are? Couldn't you get an example?

Comment: All of them. Which one to use depends on what you're doing. They've also got good javadocs.